# Can I Upgrade Reporting Services 2008 to Reporting Service 2008 R2 without upgrading SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I need to upgrade our RS 2008 server to RS 2008 R2. However, I cannot upgrade the SQL Server that it is currently using because SQL Server is on our Server Farm and we don't have authority on the farm.

Is it possible to upgrade to 2008 R2 without upgrading SQL Server 2008? anything special I need to consider before moving with the upgrade? Also, is this going to be stable configuration?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After more searching: The answer is yes:

[Installing Reporting Services 2008 R2](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/1/6/616FF1A6-9269-4A0B-83F8-D9024AA39FA5/SQLServerReportingServicesGuide.pdf)

It is mentioned on page 33

Another thing that I noticed during the process is that the account that performs the installation needs to have Local admin on the server that you are installing RS and need to be a sysadmin on the farm server during the installation. In our case we requested temporary sysadmin and revoked it when the installation was successful.